# Stucking on crashs on device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, crash, ipod-touch

I've a question within my App and I don't know how to fix this, because it's the first time of developing IOS Apps for me. The App works fine on Simulator and my Iphone 3gs. But on my Ipod touch it won't work.

So my crash log shows me something like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                0x312f488f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib               0x37632259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                0x312f7a9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3   CoreFoundation                0x312f6915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4   CoreFoundation                0x31251650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   CoreFoundation                0x3124e3fd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 53
6   UIKit                         0x3099ae07 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 63
7   UIKit                         0x3099adc3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 31
8   UIKit                         0x3099ada1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 45
9   UIKit                         0x3099ab11 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 493
10  UIKit                         0x3099b449 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 477
11  UIKit                         0x3099992b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 319
12  UIKit                         0x30999319 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 381
13  UIKit                         0x3097f695 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 357
14  UIKit                         0x3097ef3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
15  GraphicsServices              0x332c522b PurpleEventCallback + 883
16  CoreFoundation                0x312c8523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
17  CoreFoundation                0x312c84c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
18  CoreFoundation                0x312c7313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
19  CoreFoundation                0x3124a4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
20  CoreFoundation                0x3124a36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
21  GraphicsServices              0x332c4439 GSEventRunModal + 137
22  UIKit                         0x309adcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
23  My App                        0x00097045 0x95000 + 8261
24  My App                        0x00096078 0x95000 + 4216


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37f0e32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x353d9208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x353d2298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x373a1f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x3739f346 default_terminate() + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x37632350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x3739f3be safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x3739f44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib               0x373a081e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib               0x376322a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                0x3124a506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                0x3124a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices              0x332c4432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                         0x309adcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  My App                        0x0009703e 0x95000 + 8254
15  My App                        0x00096070 0x95000 + 4208

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37efe3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x35b18ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x35b18bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37efe004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37efe1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                0x312c83ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                0x312c7124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                0x3124a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                0x3124a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                       0x363eec9c RunWebThread(void*) + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3539a72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3539a5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37f0ecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37f0ecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x37f0ecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x35394cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f22bd98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe93a08
    r8: 0x0012eac0    r9: 0x373a2a4a     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x0e031d60
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe939fc      lr: 0x353d920f      pc: 0x37f0e32c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

And another thing is that some views are loading slowly and it mostly crashes on my Ipod touch 4g (on 3gs it works fine, 4 I don't know, 4s I don't know, 5 I don't know).

Sometimes it shows me on my crash logs the name of my app like this ^, and sometimes it shows me Process:Unknown Type:Unknown. Any suggestions what to do?

And in the Unknown one there's not a crash log it doesnt look like.

Comment: Could you show the code you believe is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your errors seems to have to deal with device compatibility and some people are facing the same errors like you. Take a look at this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4317775?start=0&tstart=0